# Extending functionality to object PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

I am creating a class in PHP which I want to extend so the class can have many basic functionality. The problem is that the functionality is so different and I do not want to mix the different methods in just one class. Due to organization and extensibility I prefer to separate them logically.

Let's imagine that I have three classes:

class User{ }

class Tracker { }

class Lister { }

User is the main class representing the real-life object.
Without minding on the concrete functionality of the classes, both Tracker and Lister provide methods that must be appliable in User because they are a kind of helpers. If I use inheritance I will be able to inherit just once by time having to create many classes as "extends" I will add and finishing the hierarchy with the class User. Is there any option to avoid doing this? I mean is it possible to extend User class with the functionality of the other classes without having to do in the way I have just said knowing that PHP does not support multiple inheritance?

Thank you!

Comment: Extending the User class here isn't a good example of the Single Responsibility principle: depending on what Tracker and Lister do, consider Dependency Injection

Comment: Create an interface and have each class implement it.

Comment: Are the methods of Lister and Tracker conceptually something a User will do? Or are they something the User has ownership of?

Comment: Both classes are helpers. They provide functionality that I do not want to include into the original class.

Comment: Both classes are helpers. They provide functionality that I do not want to include into the original class. For example I created a class that injects some methods inside a class (the one I created consists on adding the functionality of SetAttr and GetAttr allowing me to use it like the method like this $user->SetAttr('attribute', value);

Answer (score 0):

It the classes help or decorate the User class, it may be better to use an implementation of the decorator pattern.

```
$user = new User();
//default behavior
$user->getMethod();

$tracker = new Tracker($user);
//enhanced behavior
$tracker->getMethod();
```